# Plugin Addthis: open addthis onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, addthis

how can I launch a modal window addthis after a click on the button.
I've tried:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.share').live('click', function() {
        var addthis_config =
        {
            data_track_addressbar: true,
            services_compact: "email, facebook, twitter, google_plusone_share, gmail, pinterest"
        }
        addthis.button('.share', [addthis_config], [{}]);
        }); 
    </script>
```

In this way it works, just that I have to do 2 clicks to open the modal window.
Link in my template:

```
<a class="share">Share</a>
```

Comment: Each time you click on an .share button, you are initializing a new addThis button, looks wrong!  Isn't addThis using iFrame to render social button? If Iframe is cross domain, you cannot do what you are looking for but i don't use addThis, so i'm just guessing about iFrame

Answer (score 1):

The code you're using will make the .share element a button, but not open it. To open the AddThis modal window you need to fire a second click event using something like this:

```
$('.share').click();
```

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Comment: $('.share').click() is all you need. Just put it after the addthis.button line.